# Antrl4 parsing - tackling difficult syntax

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am parsing a language which has some difficult syntax that I need some help or suggestions to tackle it.

Heres an a typical line =>

```
IF CLCI((ZNTEM+CHRCNT),1,1H())) EQ 0
```

The difficult bit is `nH(....any character within the character set.....)` where `n` is 1 in this example and the single char in question is a `')'` . My lexer has:

```
fragment Lp: '(';
fragment Rp: ')';

LP: Lp;
RP: Rp; etc....
```

My current non-working solution is to switch modes in the lexer because then I can then define all the special chars to consume

```
// Default mode rules
STRING_SUB: INT 'H' LP -> pushMode(ISLAND) ; // switch to ISLAND mode
```

and then to switch back

```
// Special mode of INT H ( ID )
// ID is the string substitute which can includes, spaces, backslash, etc, special chars

mode ISLAND;

ISLAND_CLOSE : RP -> popMode ; // back to nomal mode

ID : SpecialChars+; // match/send ID in tag to parser

fragment SpecialChars: '\u0020'..'\u0027' | '\u002A'..'\u0060' | '\u0061'..'\u007E' | '¦';
```

But obviously the pop mode trigger is the `')'` which fails in the particular example case, because the payload is a RP. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that you could see multiple ')' in the '(.....)' set (there's no restriction it seems to prevent the user from doing that). If you ignore that problem, you can write a lexer that can scan ahead to determine whether the ')' ends of the character set, then have a semantic predicate that indicates the end of the character set. You may have to look back to see previous '(' chars. Otherwise, you have to make this a per-character parser (aka "scannerless parser"). Antlr's lexer operates independently of the parser more or less.

Comment: Thx for the reply, looking into semantic predicates now, looks promising for what I wantr ot do. I had forgotten about them to be honest.